# Create subscription with URL including Bearer Token in the header

Tags: token, subscription, fiware

Hello FIWARE specialists,
I like to create a subscription, which pushes notifications to an external service.
The external service needs authorization with a barrier token.
If I use curl, I add "--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXX'".
How can I add a barrier token to the subscription request?

```
"notification": {
    "attributes": [ "id", "type", "name", "location", "occupancy"],
    "format": "normalized",
    "endpoint": { 
        "uri": "http://a.b.c.de:1111", 
        "accept": "application/json"
    }
  },
```

Is there an option to add a header field to the "endpoint" setup in the subscription like:

```
"headers": "Authorization: Bearer XXX"
```

Hopefully, you can help me in that case.
Thanks, Knigge

Comment: If you could reformulate the question in NGSIv2 terms (maybe in a separate post) I can provide you some answer.

Comment: so I try to reformulate my question in NGSIv2 context ...
I like to create a subscription, which pushes notifications to an external service. The external service needs authorization with a barrier token. 
How can I add a barrier token to the body when I create a subscription?
If I create  a subscription via
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://context-provider:3000/subscription/low-stock-store001",
      "headers": "Authorization: Bearer XXX"
    },
    "attrsFormat" : "keyValues"
  }

the creations seem successful.

Comment: If I request the subscription again, the "headers" entry is not inside anymore, so it was not saved. 
What is the right way to implement the Bearer Token in the subscription definition?

Comment: Is this problem detected in Orion or Orion-LD? I have the impression it's Orion-LD and in such case it's a bug of mine. If so, please create an issue on Orion-LD's github, as detailed as possible:  https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/issues

Answer (score 0):

In Orion Context Broker using the NGSIv2 API you can use [custom notifications](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#custom-notifications) to achieve that. For example the following subscription:

```
...
"httpCustom": {
  "url": "http://context-provider:3000/subscription/low-stock-store001",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer XXX"
  }
}
```